# NullPointerException when accessing EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I am using Hibernate4,Spring3 and JSF2 for a small application and Weblogic 10.3.6 as Apps server.

In order to enable JPA2 I have added the following in commEnv.cmd

```
@rem Enable JPA 2.0 functionality on WebLogic Server
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%BEA_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar;
%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
```

When I run my application I am getting null pointer exception at the following line. How can I resolve this?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
```

My DAO

```
@Named
public class RequestDAOImpl implements RequestDAO {

protected EntityManager entityManager;

public void getRequest(RequestQueryData data){
        Map<String, String> filters = data.getFilters();
        int start = data.getStart();
        int end = data.getEnd();
        String sortField = data.getSortField();
        QuerySortOrder order = data.getOrder();

        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Request> c = cb.createQuery(Request.class);
        Root<Request> emp = c.from(Request.class);
        c.select(emp);
                ...... other code
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="org.primefaces.spring.scope.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:ORCL" />
        <property name="user" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>     
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.test.model.Request</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Update 1

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Spring view scope customized -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="org.primefaces.spring.scope.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:ORCL" />
        <property name="user" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>
      <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
         <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
         <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.test.model" />
         <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
       </bean>
   </property>         
      </bean> 
      <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />        
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.test.model.Request</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />-->
    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined 
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>-->

     <!-- Transaction Config -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
          <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
          </bean>   

          <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>         

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>  
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>             

     <context:annotation-config/>


    <bean id="hibernateStatisticsMBean" class="org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService">
        <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" value="#{entityManagerFactory.sessionFactory}" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ehCacheManagerMBean"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmxExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
        <property name="registrationBehaviorName" value="REGISTRATION_REPLACE_EXISTING"/>
        <property name="beans">
            <map>               
                <entry key="SpringBeans:name=hibernateStatisticsMBean" value-ref="hibernateStatisticsMBean" />
                <entry key="SpringBeans:name=ehCacheManagerMBean" value-ref="ehCacheManagerMBean" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your EntityManager doesn't appear to be wired into your DAO. Add `@Autowired`, `@PersistenceContext` or a ref in your XML. Note that to just use `@Autowired`, you'll have to specify EntityManager as a bean.

Another possibility: if your DAO isn't also specified as a bean (either in the XML or using one of the various `@Component` annotatons (probably `@Repository`), Spring won't know to wire things in, either.

Update:
There's a couple different solutions here. Before those, though, make sure that you have

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

In one of your XMLs. This will enable the spring annotations and save you a lot of headache from editing XMLs. Note that you'll also need to update the xmlns and schemaLocation in the `<beans>` tag.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

and

```
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

in the schemaLocation.

It looks like you're now specifying an `EntityManagerFactory`. That's a good start. You can now specify an `EntityManager`, too.

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I can't vouch for your XML and `EntityManagerFactory` settings, though. You seem to have an `</property>` floating out there in the middle of nowhere.

I'm not sure how you're accessing your DAO. If it's already a bean and within the component-scan, you're good. If not, make sure to annotate your DAO class with `@Repository` and make sure its package is within the component-scan. Of course, if you don't already have it specified as a bean, that implies that you're possibly instantiating it elsewhere --  this is absolutely not how you want to be using your DAO. Should this be the case, I strongly recommend reading up on Spring's dependency injection.

Now you need to wire in your `EntityManager`. This can be done in two ways.

The first way requires that you specified it as a bean in your XML. If you've done that, just annotate your `EntityManager` field.

```
@Autowired
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Alternatively, since you're specifying a DataSource in your XML, you SHOULD be able to reference it by using `@PersistenceContext` and passing it a value of the ID.

```
@PersistenceContext(name="DataSource")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

I've never really used the latter method, but I've seen it done that way. I normally specify an `EntityManager` bean in the XML and use `@Autowired`, as described in the former method.

Comment: I have a question, when I used another method `@Override
 public List<Request> getRequest() {,` it worked without any exceptions or errors.

Comment: And that was accessing the EntityManager? Does it only throw a NPE when calling getCriteriaBuilder()?

Comment: No I was not accessing EntityManager at all. I have modified my applicationContext.xml, included as Update 1 in my question. I am still getting null pointer exception at `CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();`

Comment: @Polppan - I've updated my answer, now that the problem does appear to be a problem with the dependency being injected. Be careful -- your new XML appears to be badly-formed. I see an `</property>` tag that doesn't appear to have an opening tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with Entity Manager. I have made some progress and managed to get rid of all exceptions at deployment time. Currently stuck with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987662/classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-hqltoken-even-after-addin) :-)

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out EntityManager problem, issues has been resolved.